# Паника, не понимаю из за чего

Tags: golang

От чего может ловиться паника в данном случае?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("test")
    td := make([]int, 2)
    td[0] = 16
    td[1] = 256
    td[2] = 24
    var test2 string
    test2 = IntSliceToString(td)
    fmt.Println(test2)
}

func IntSliceToString(td[]int) string{
    var result string
    for i:=1; i<=2; i++ {
        fmt.Println(td[i])
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Вы делаете срез длины 2 и пишете в третий элемент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическая ошибка, дело в том что при создание любого массива его размер исчисляется с 0, т.е. при создание массива длинной 2 его иднексы будут 0 и 1
td := make([]int, 2)
td[0], td[1] но не td[3]